# Any word on "real" plugin plans for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins

Chrome devs often talk about their plugin plans, but I am still unsure what kind of plugins  they mean. Are they working in the direction of real firefox-like plugins that can deeply interact with browser engine and interface, or they have no intentions of going beyond current javascript userscripts?

Answer (score 3):

The [wishlist](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/apiwishlist) of extension APIs suggests that they intend to allow deeper interaction with the browser in the future.

A list of more details of some of the proposed APIs [is here](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions). Interesting looking ones include the [Gleam API](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/gleam-api) that looks like it'll provide an easy interface for interacting with DOM objects.

There is further discussion about the changing design on the [Chromium developer mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/chromium-dev)

Answer (score 2):

The [samples they posted](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/samples) show promise.  Ultimately it is just scripting, but with the ability to significantly modify the browser environment, it looks like they can achieve much the same level of plugins we find in Firefox.  I for one am looking forward to it, though the last time I tried Chromium it was crash after crash.

More examples here: http://www.chromeplugins.org/google/chrome-plugins/chrome-extensions-bookmarklets-userscripts-compilation-7510.html

Comment: Those plugins have pretty much no control over browser or rendering engine. All it allow you to do is to add some javascript buttons with built-in css to the browser status bar.